# javaws failing on JNLP file, unable to verify cert error

Tags: java, jvm

We run Screenconnect at the office, or whatever connectwise calls it these days.

I'm the only linux user in the office. So I just run the icedtea-netx plugin and open my sessions with the jnlp file.

Recently had to reload a laptop and noticed that I can no longer open any jnlp file from our screenconnect server.   Also noticed that default is now openjdk 11, not 8.

It's still working on my office machine,which is running the 1.8 version of the iced tea plugin.

I installed the openjdk 8 jdk and set it as default. same issue. 
I changed both 11 and 8's java.security to allow md5, no change.

I can't just go back to the icedtea-8 plugin. I got stumped at dependencies, mainly xulrunner I think it was.

Here's the java console output.

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:822)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945) Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars. An exception has been thrown in class JarCertVerifier. Being unable to read the cacerts or trusted.certs files could be a possible cause for this exception.: zip END header not found     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:739)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)     ... 2 more 
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:822)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:531)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945) Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars. An exception has been thrown in class JarCertVerifier. Being unable to read the cacerts or trusted.certs files could be a possible cause for this exception.: zip END header not found     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:739)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:338)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:421)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)     at java.desktop/net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:814)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug on Connectwise's side.  They get the same error upon spinning up a new debian instance and installing icedtea-netx.

Supposedly this was in 19.2 and older.  It was supposedly fixed in 19.3 but we upgraded to 19.5 and it's still broken.  We went to 19.5 after I was told by their support that he tested it in 19.5 and it worked. Same error.

Waiting on a fix for this, it's been escalated to development.   I'll update once/if they fix it.